Anyone know why a "hard" refresh in Safari is loading css/js/image twice? This isn't happening with Chrome
I'm trying to figure out how I might stop Safari from "double fetching" assets on a web page when I do option-command-r (a hard refresh):

I have verified it is indeed hitting the server twice by looking at apache's access logs for the site.
This is not happening when I do shift-command-r on Chrome. Anyone have any ideas how to prevent Safari from doing this? It's happening on two different macs.

Does it only happen with this specific, locally-hosted website, or with all?

I just tested on the NYT site. It happens there, too. Looks like most jpg images loaded 6 different times with a hard refresh, but only once with a regular refresh. Very weird.

Do things change if you disable all extensions in Safari?

I have no extensions. Are you able to duplicate this problem on your machine?

Will try later today, not at home right now.

See the same thing.

FWIW On Safari 18.1 on macOS Ventura, using the option key held down alternate for View -> Reload Page from Origin, I get 2, or 4 (!!!!) copies of almost every file on a page.

I think that you may have one of the development tools active.  This happens on other browsers if this is the case.

This behavior does not happen with Chrome's development tool active.

This you can not control from the server side. Not a issue just browser-specific functionality that happens across multiple sites, not just yours. Unfortunately, there isn't a straightforward fix to prevent Safari from doing this.
